# Batch which carries out a command when a button is pressed while running a loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to run a loop and have it so that if a certain key is pressed the loop ends, something like what is below although that does not work.
Also the loop has to continue running and not stop while waiting for a input from the user.

```
@echo off
:start
echo 1
IF "a"=="" GOTO end
goto :start
:end
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works automatically in all batch scripts, as long as the certain key is `Ctrl+C`.

Otherwise, you need a check at each iteration of your loop (like you have), and another process to monitor the keyboard.

```
:: Allocate a probably-unique filename
set SENTINELFILE=%temp%\sentinel-%random%-%time:~6,5%.lck

:: Should probably do something less destructive if the file already exists
:: like loop and find another name. But this is a prototype.
copy /y NUL %SENTINELFILE%

:: Opens a new cmd window which prompts the user to press X
:: then deletes the sentinel and exits
:: Could also run another batch file or exe that does something we can detect
start "End Task" %comspec% /c choice /c x /M "Press X to end task" ^& del %SENTINELFILE%

:topofloop

:: TODO: Process some part of your work to be done

:: Loop as long as the sentinel file exists
if exist %SENTINELFILE% goto :topofloop
```

Comment: SENTINELFILE is not being deleted so the loop just continues.

Comment: I tried doing this:
del "%SENTINELFILE%"
In another batch file it it permanently deleted almost everything off my desktop. I managed to recover the files using another program though.

Comment: Typo in the script.  Remove /y from del command.  Works here now.  Not sure what happened with your desktop, but your SENTINELFILE variable probably pointed to a directory instead of a filename.  You should probably test in a temp folder and not the desktop folder.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is multi-thread (one thread taking input and one running the loop). There are a few tricky ways of doing this. However, to save you time and effort, a cheap trick you can do is hold the loop every iteration for a second and wait for input using the `choice` command:

```
@echo off
:start
echo 1
choice /c "qa" /d q /t 1 /n /m "Press a to Stop Loop: "
if %errorlevel%==2 goto end
cls
goto :start
:end
pause
```

Which will stop it once a second to check for input as `a`